# Photo library KGDB files, mac os x ventura

Tags: mac, photos, database, ventura

I have recently updated to Ventura, and the photos app changed a bit. Before the update the photos app used mostly sqlite to store all the data, but now it changed to files with `.kgdb` extension. I can see there are `.wal` - write ahead logs files as well, but i cant figure out what is that database.. Does anyone have any further information what standard it is?